# xamarin with asp.net identity 2.0

Tags: android, ios, asp.net, xamarin

I need some help here. I don't know where to start from. I have got a web site that I have developed with ASP.NET web forms, c# and have used the ASP.NET identity 2.0

Now, I need to build an android app by using Xamarin. Is there a way to authenticate users against that asp.net database?

I have been looking all around and nothing that I have found.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you need to write for example a WebApi query for Login() and Logout() which will call the underlying logic. You can use HttpClient for communication, and you'll need to store and retrieve the authentication cookie (if you're using cookie based auth).

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into Token Based Authentication using ASP.NET Web API 2, Owin, and Identity? You can create an authentication server based on your Asp.net Identity. This can be used to secure your resource.

I suggest you visit this tutorial on [Microsoft Asp.Net Site](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api) or create a new Web API project with authentication to understand the concept. I hope that helps.